# Bootstrap Correlation in R. How to get bootstrapped r coefficient, p.value, Confidence Interval

Tags: r, correlation, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to do a bootstrapped correlation in R.

Following what I saw in these two posts: [How can I get confidence intervals for a one-tailed, bootstrapped Pearson correlation in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57902348/how-can-i-get-confidence-intervals-for-a-one-tailed-bootstrapped-pearson-correl) and [Bootstrapped p-value for a correlation coefficient on R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51761415/bootstrapped-p-value-for-a-correlation-coefficient-on-r) I tried the following:

```
x = data$myData1
y = data$myData2
dat <- data.frame(x, y)
set.seed(1)
bootCorTest3 <- function(data, i){
  d <- data[i, ]
  results  <- cor.test(d$x, d$y)
  c(est = results$estimate, stat = results$statistic, param = results$parameter, p.value = results$p.value, CI = results$conf.int)
}

b3 <- boot(dat, bootCorTest3, R = 2000)
b3

OUTPUT:
Bootstrap Statistics :
       original       bias    std. error
t1*  0.29836749 -0.012284427   0.1492960
t2*  2.16580050 -0.013933040   1.2160051
t3* 48.00000000  0.000000000   0.0000000
t4*  0.03532486  0.107464681   0.2207419
t5*  0.02183300 -0.006166465   0.1612371
t6*  0.53249181 -0.014324511   0.1206106

# Original (non-bootstrap) statistics with label
b3$t0

    est.cor      stat.t    param.df     p.value         CI1         CI2 
 0.29836749  2.16580050 48.00000000  0.03532486  0.02183300  0.53249181 

colMeans(b2$t)

2.1395137 0.1298312 0.2854631

boot.ci(b, type = c("norm", "basic", "perc", "bca"))

Intervals : 
Level      Normal              Basic         
95%   (-0.5130,  0.3679 )   (-0.7692,  0.0706 )  

Level     Percentile            BCa          
95%   ( 0.0000,  0.8399 )   ( 0.0000,  0.8581 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
```

So, I see that I can get the non bootstrapped statistics, which are quite clear to me, by running: `b3$t0`. But I don't understand how do I get the bootstrapped p.value and r coefficient. Also, the output if I type b3 (bootstrap statistics) is not clear to me. Can anyone help me understand?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Sorry about that, should I move it?